# PostGIS calculate distance to every point in table

Tags: postgis, st-distance

I would like to calculate distance from point made by putting coordinate manually to every point in table. I made that code:

```
SELECT a.name 
FROM ne_110m_populated_places as a 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT ST_Point(20, 50)::geography AS ref_geog) As r
WHERE ST_DWithin(a.geom, ref_geog, 10000000)
ORDER BY ST_Distance(a.geom, ref_geog);
```

And it is working fine but I don't know how to add distance to output table as a column with value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply run

```
SELECT name,
       ST_Distance(geom, 'POINT(20 50)'::GEOGRAPHY) AS dist
FROM   ne_110m_populated_places
ORDER BY
       2
;
```

or, if you want to outsource the reference geometry creation, use a CTE

```
WITH
  ref AS (
    SELECT 'POINT(20 50)'::GEOGRAPHY AS geom
  )

SELECT name,
       ST_Distance(a.geom, b.geom) AS dist
FROM   ne_110m_populated_places AS a,
       ref AS b
ORDER BY
       2
;
```

Comment: Thanks for posting it, this is way simpler to read. I'm getting hard time learning postgis, cannot find some nice examples that teach common tasks in postgis.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out:

```
SELECT a.name, ST_Distance(a.geom, r.ref_geog) 
FROM ne_110m_populated_places as a 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT ST_Point(20, 50)::geography AS ref_geog) As r
WHERE ST_DWithin(a.geom, ref_geog, 10000000)
ORDER BY ST_Distance(a.geom, ref_geog);
```